# javaFX stage work fine on netbeans IDE but dosen't on build

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

when i try to open new window it works fine on netbeans ide but it dosen't on builded jar nor it does throw an exception 
this is my code

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/gui/journal/AddToJournalElement.fxml"));
    AnchorPane panel = loader.load();
    AddToJournalElementController windowController = loader.<AddToJournalElementController>getController();
    windowController.init(journalElementsTableView, journal);
    Scene secondScene = new Scene(panel);
    Stage newWindow = new Stage();
    newWindow.setTitle("Ajouter");
    newWindow.setScene(secondScene);
    newWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    newWindow.initOwner(MainWindow.primary);
    newWindow.setWidth(600);
    newWindow.setHeight(560);
    newWindow.setResizable(false);
    newWindow.show();
```

Comment: Run your `Jar` using the `Command Prompt`.

Comment: You should build that as a runnable JAR.

Comment: thank you don't know how i didn't try that